# How do I make particles like the "flashing" ones in this YouTube video?

Tags: animation, effects

I just want to know how to create this flashing effect. Specifically the lighting effect on the minecraft character's eyes. See an example at 0:14 in:

[[image: Flash Effect]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_Ru7khHSdM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_Ru7khHSdM&t=14s)

Comment: Maybe look at smoke simulation. It could be emitted with particles setup appropriately.

Comment: This may be of interest to you. (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18961/how-to-achieve-a-burning-wireframe-effect/46692#46692)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pass index for the material of the eyes, then use that to create a blur on the compositor.

[image]

More info on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing)